# How do I get claims included in my AuthTicket in a Web API Auth Service?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

I have a Web API with an auth service, for a WPF client, set up like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true, // TODO Make false to deploy
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

I only ever use the `/Token` endpoint so far, because it at least grants me the bearer token. The ticket I receive on a successful authentication has issue and expiry dates, a bearer token, and my username.

How do I get the user's claims (and maybe roles)? Is there something I can do here, or I do I plod along and request them via the API, after auth, and aggregate them and the Auth Ticket in something like a `Principal` object for the WPF client?

Could I perhaps include some Identity components in the WPF app to help with extracting the claims from the token, and any suggestions on how I should do this?

Comment: All information is encrypted inside the token itself, so to get to it you have to decrypt the token. Of course you cannot have a decryption key on the client - only on server. So yes - you have to request them via API after auth (in theory you could send them together with your auth response, but not sure if built-in oauth has such possibility).

Comment: But I don't need a DB lookup to request them, just decode the auth token I have to send anyway, and send back the claims. If you please, any hint on how to decrypt the token? Or is it a long story?

Comment: You want to avoid separate call to your service to get claims? Want to get them together with token itself (so, from call to the /token endpoint)?

Comment: Also, can you add the code for your ApplicationOAuthProvider.

Comment: Is the data actually encrypted or is it just base 64 encoded?

Comment: You need to validate and then decrypt the token. As metioned in another comment, the best place for doing so is on a trusted API that is executed server side. See the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303426/what-is-considered-best-practice-for-user-authentication-authorization-for-wpf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is quite dangerous to allow the client to decrypt the token. If they can do that, a malicious actor can modify the token and the claims inside. If you don't check the validity of the claims (perhaps because they are provided by a third party) then that could lead to privilege escalation and compromise of your application.

If the client application requires the claims - perhaps for UI layout, then you can supply them separately to the token. One way to do this would be via an [ActionFilterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to write the claims to a custom http header. If the claims are tampered with here, it only affects the client, as you will check the secure claims inside the token before processing any request.

```
public AddClaimsAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
     var principal = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

    if (principal != null)
    {
        var claims = principal.Claims.Select(x => x.Type + ":" + x.Value).ToList();

        actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Claims",
           String.Join(",", claims));
    }

}
```

Your client then just needs to check for this header and parse it.

This is a basic example, you could format it as JSON or add a series of custom headers "IsAdmin", "IsEditingUser" etc.

Because it is a filter, you could apply this globally to every request, to every action on a controller or to a specific action as you need it.

Comment: I felt like I should point out that decrypting claims can be an easy task if the tokens are signed (thus forged tokens can't be sent back because they can't be signed back). JWT, for example, runs like this.

Comment: @maverick True, but JWT is not without it's flaws.https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/

Comment: That can be said if pretty much anything in software world. However, even in your link the problem is with implementations and not the token standard itself, and .net implementation library didn't appear to suffer from that. Even if it did, the fix would be posted and its our job to keep up with updates

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this by adding user roles in token response. In order to do this you have to update in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs class the method CreateProperties

```
     public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(User user)
            {
//get only roles ids
//to do: retrieve user roles names 
                var roles = string.Join(",", user.Roles.Select(t => t.RoleId).ToArray());
//expose phone in response
                var phone = user.PhoneNumber;
                IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "userName", user.UserName },
                    { "userId", user.Id },
                    { "roles", roles},
                    { "phone", phone}
                };
                return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
            }
```

You can see in postman response 3 new properties: userId,roles and phone. Be carrefull for null values when you will add new properties.

[image]